# Can't connect to server via SSH outside Web Console

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall

If I try to connect to my server via any console, etc.:

```
➤ ssh -vv xx.xx.xxx.xx:1337
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
_ssh: Could not resolve hostname xx.xx.xxx.xx:1337: Name or service not known
```

Obviously something is not working.

Good thing is that I can connect to it via browser with Web Console (provided by Vultr). And if I type same thing on web console `ssh root@xx.xx.xxx.xx -p 1337` it logs me in.

I stopped `UFW` firewall and reset my `iptables`. Ports look OK.

[image: Screenshot]

Why I can't login to my server via consoles?

**update:** Apparently the local environment I was using to connect was blocking ssh, after unblocking it and running `ssh -p 1337 root@xx.xx.xxx.xx` I get this:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting via `ssh xx.xx.xxx.xx -p 1337`? In some places, `:` is no longer allowed to specifiy the port, so you have to use `-p` (e.g. in the mysql client), and in my tries, I also could not connect to my servers adding the port via :.

Comment: @DavidGeorgReichelt may as well post that as an answer.

Comment: Have a look into the server log, if you can notice a reason why the connection was reset.

Comment: @Jakuje auth.log reports only "sshd[3354]: refused connect from my_ip (my_ip)"

Comment: What is the complete error message you can see there. There is no such error message in OpenSSH that would say "refused connect".

Comment: @Jakuje http://i.imgur.com/gO1jC6h.png

Comment: What Ubuntu version is on that server? Can you set up `LogLevel DEBUG3` in server configuration, restart sshd service, try to connect again and send the logs again? The context of that message might help.

Comment: @Jakuje http://i.imgur.com/fZjsoCe.png 16.04.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual page for `ssh` clearly explains the synopsis of the `ssh` command:

```
 ssh [...] [-p port] [...] [user@]hostname [...]
```

You can not add a port after the `hostname`. You should use the following:

```
ssh -p 1337 xx.xx.xxx.xx
```

**Edit after gathering more details:** The important part is

```
connection refused by tcp_wrapper
```

Your server is configured to refuse connections from some IP addresses in `/etc/hosts.allow` and/or `/etc/hosts.deny`. Review these rules and adjust them if you want to be able to ssh from your IP.

Comment: now I get "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

Comment: I updated the answer with the reasons for the reject.

Comment: fixed! but how did my ip got added to the bottom of hosts.deny list?

Comment: It could have been added by `fail2ban` or similar tool running on the server and banning clients trying to authenticate (and failing) too often.

Comment: It was `denyhosts` service.